# Does the centraliser of the intersection of any two Sylow $p$-subgroups contain all Sylow $p$-subgroups?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Consider a collection of Sylow $p$-subgroups. 
If any two of these intersect non-trivially then they are both contained within the centraliser of their intersection. Now assume that $P_1$ and $P_2$ are abelian I believe if $P_1, P_2$ are abelian then obviously every one of the elements of this group must commute with those in $Q$. ($Q$ denotes the intersection of these $P$)

My Question:

I read that given the case where there were $4$ Sylow $3$-subgroups of order $9$ that the fact that $P_1,P_2 \leq C_G(Q)$ implies that there are at least $2$ Sylow $3$-subgroups are contained in it. And so it contains at least $1+3=4$.

So in other words it contains all of them. so my question is can we assume if $P_1,P_2,P_3,P_4$ are all abelian and of the same order that then the centraliser of the intersection of any two of then a subgroup which contains every $P$ a $p$-Sylow subgroup?

Comment: Why must they be abelian?

Comment: or more concisely every group of order $p^{\alpha}, \alpha \geq 1$ is abelian

Comment: @exodius Is the [quaternion group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_group) abelian?

Comment: So a group of order 27 for example must be abelian?

Comment: @the_fox I'm trying to find where I read that but now I can only find its true for $p^2$ perhaps I misunderstood and it's neccarily true beyond this ?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen ah yes I see know.... the quaternions are non abelian and order 8 . thank you

Comment: I've edited it to make more sense :)

Comment: What is $Q$? It's not clear.

Comment: My apologies I meant Q to denote the intersection of the sylow p-subgroups

Answer (score 1):

You wrote:

*I read that given the case where there were 4 Sylow $3$-subgroups of order $9$ that the fact that $P_1,P_2≤C_G(Q)$ implies that there are at least $2$ Sylow $3$-subgroups are contained in it. And so it contains at least $1+3=4$.*

This follows immediately from Sylow theory in $C_G(Q)$, since $n_{C_G(Q)} \equiv 1$ mod $3$ and $\{P_1,P_2\} \subseteq Syl_3(C_G(Q))$.

Another remark:

You also wrote: *If any two of these intersect non-trivially then they are both contained within the centraliser of their intersection*.

This is not necessarily true: $P_1 \cap P_2$ in general does not lie in the center $Z(P_1)$ or $Z(P_2)$.